# How can detect one string contain one of several characters using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a variable length string, I just want to detect whether this string contains several characters. For example:

```
"sadsdd$sss^dee~"
```

I want to detect whether this string contains ANY of the following: `$` `^` `~`. How can I do that using Java `string.matches`?

```
"sadsdd$sss^dee~".matches("[^+$+~+]");
```

Comment: You would need to loop for each characters separately.

Comment: Does your string need to contain all of `$` `^` `~` characters or one is enough?

Answer (score 5):

Use a pattern and a matcher for that:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[$~^]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
   // contains special characters
} else {
   // doesn't contain special characters
}
```

Comment: @BalintBako: no need to escape within a character class.

Comment: Although it is not what OP is asking it is better approach. +1

Comment: @Pshemo: Do you think OPs question is to check the existence of all 3 cahracters?

Comment: No, I mean that OP was asking about `string.matches()` solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use `matches` then try this way

```
myString.matches(".*[$^~].*");
```

`matches` checks if regex can completely match string so beside part you are interested with you also need to let it match parts before and after it, which `.*` should handle.

Answer (score 1):

How to detect if one string contains one of several characters in another string:

If you want a fast solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(containsChars("sadsdd$sss^dee~", "$^~"));
}

public static boolean containsChars(String str, String chars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        char c = chars.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if (c == str.charAt(j)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Certainly not as small or elegant as a regular expression, but it is fast.

Comment: This doesn't seen to be really fast because if the string doesn't contain any of the chars, it needs to make m*n iterations. Would this still perform better than matching a regex (even if the regex is pre-compiled)?

Comment: Short answer: Yes! More fastes that regex.